# How to render this map-reduce javascript code to an equivalent LINQ Select-Aggregate?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, select

How to render this map-reduce javascript function to an equivalent c# LINQ Select-Aggregate syntax?

```
/**
 * Multiply transforms into one.
 *
 * @param {Array} input transforms array
 * @return {Array} output matrix array
 */
exports.transformsMultiply = function(transforms) {

    // convert transforms objects to the matrices
    transforms = transforms.map(function(transform) {
        if (transform.name === 'matrix') {
            return transform.data;
        }
        return transformToMatrix(transform);
    });

    // multiply all matrices into one
    transforms = {
        name: 'matrix',
        data: transforms.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return multiplyTransformMatrices(a, b);
        })
    };

    return transforms;

};
```

Comment: You had a dictionary as the tag to this posting.  So the dictionary would look like this :             var matrices = transforms.GroupBy(x => x.a, y => y.b)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

Comment: @jdweng Thank you. But what if I have also a dictionary as the input parameter 'transforms'? Something like: Dictionary<string,decimal[]> , where decimal[] is the array of the matrix coefficients?

Comment: How does a single array map to (a,b)?

Comment: @jdweng The reduce equivalent of C# is the Aggregate method. With that method the parameters (a, b) are the elements [i] and [i+1] of the same single array. You can find a good explanation here: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-aggregation-operator-aggregate

Comment: The example doesn't show "matrix coefficients".  Coefficients are normally constant multipliers against the terms.  The example is just showing the array of terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct equivalent would look something like this:

```
public Transform TransformsMultiply(IEnumerable<Transform> transforms)
{
    var matrices = transforms.Select(transform =>
        transform.Name == "matrix"
            ? transform.Data
            : transformToMatrix(transform));

    return new Transform
    {
        Name = "matrix",
        Data = matrices.Aggregate((a, b) =>
            multiplyTransformMatrices(a, b));
    };
}
```

Of course you will need to define the `Transform` class and the `transformToMatrix` and `multiplyTransformMatrices` methods;

Though differentiating types of transforms by the `Name` property is not idiomatic C#. It would be much better if you created an abstract base `Transform` type and subclasses for each type of transform:

```
public abstract class Transform { /* ... */ }

public class Matrix : Transform
{
    public int[,] Data { get; set; }
}

public class OtherTypeOfTransform : Transform
{
    /* ... */
}
```

The first part of the method would then look like:

```
var matrices = transforms.Select(transform =>
    transform is Matrix 
        ? transform.Data 
        : transformToMatrix(transform));
```

But that is not very object oriented because `transformToMatrix` needs to know how to convert each type of transform into a matrix. You should consider adding an abstract `ToMatrix` method to the base class and implementing it in the subclasses, thereby delegating the responsibility of converting itself into a matrix to each subclass.

```
public abstract class Transform
{
    public abstract Matrix ToMatrix();
}

public class Matrix : Transform
{
    public int[,] Data { get; set; }

    public Matrix ToMatrix() { return this; }
}

public class OtherTypeOfTransform : Transform
{
    public Matrix ToMatrix()
    {
        // Type-specific implementation
    }
}
```

After that, the implementation would look like this:

```
public Matrix TransformsMultiply(IEnumerable<Transform> transforms)
{
    return new Matrix
    {
        Data = transforms
            .Select(transform => transform.ToMatrix())
            .Aggregate((a, b) => multiplyTransformMatrices(a, b));
    };
}
```

Moving the multiplication into the `Matrix` class makes this even nicer:

```
public Matrix TransformsMultiply(IEnumerable<Transform> transforms)
{
    return new Matrix
    {
        Data = transforms
            .Select(transform => transform.ToMatrix())
            .Aggregate((a, b) => a.MultiplyBy(b));
    };
}
```

And that's how I would convert that JavaScript into idiomatic object-oriented C# code.

**EDIT**

You asked how I would implement this using a `Dictionary<string, decimal[]>` instead of `IEnumerable<Transform>`, so here it is:

```
public KeyValuePair<string, decimal[]> TransformsMultiply(
    Dictionary<string, decimal[]> transforms)
{
    var matrices = transforms.Select(kvp =>
        kvp.Key == "matrix"
            ? kvp.Value
            : transformToMatrix(kvg.Value));

    return new KeyValuePair<string, int>(
        "matrix", 
        matrices.Aggregate((a, b) => multiplyTransformMatrices(a, b));
}
```

A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, so in this solution, a transform is represented by a `KeyValuePair<string, decimal[]>`.

Please note that dictionary keys are unique so you can only have one transform with the key `"matrix"`. I'm not sure if that's what you want.

The disadvantages of this solution are that:

- you can only have one instance of each type of transform because of dictionary key uniqueness
- it obscures the intent of the code and makes it much harder to read (in my opinion
- behavior that logically belongs to the transform itself (how to convert it into a matrix and how to multiply a matrix by another matrix) is now not encapsulated, and it is inside the `transformToMatrix` and `multiplyTransformMatrices` methods.

If you really want a generic container for the transforms instead of a named class, you can use `Tuple<T, U>`:

```
public Tuple<string, decimal[]> TransformsMultiply(
    IEnumerable<Tuple<string, decimal[]>> transforms)
{
    var matrices = transforms.Select(t =>
        t.Item1 == "matrix" ? t.Item2 : transformToMatrix(t.Item2));

    return new Tuple<string, decimal[]>(
        "matrix",
        matrices.Aggregate((a, b) => multiplyTransformMatrices(a, b)));
}
```

Here you can have multiple transforms with the same name but the second and the third disadvantages mentioned above still apply.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Comment: And what if I have a dictionary as the 'transforms'? Something like: Dictionary<string,decimal[]> , where decimal[] is the array of the matrix coefficients? And Name and Data are the Key and Value properties of the Dictionary entry?

Comment: That would work too, but only one dictionary item could have the key "matrix". I'm not sure if that's what you want. I'll add an answer using a dictionary. But I wouldn't recommend doing it that way.

Comment: Thank you very much for this further clarification! I will use the named class instead then.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)